# Show XML file in WinForms app with IE-like coloring and collapsing nodes

Tags: .net, xml, winforms

I would like to show an XML file in my .NET 2.0 WinForms app just like IE does (where you can collapse the nodes, and everything is nicely colored). Is there a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can host IE inside your application's form or you can display it in the WebBrowser control using the same XSL transform that IE uses as described here: http://blorgh.wordpress.com/2006/10/17/displaying-xml-in-the-net-webbrowser-control/

Answer (score 1):

On codeplex there is a project [XmlVisualiser v.2](http://www.codeplex.com/XmlVisualizer) that will do this. It works both as a visualzer add-in for Visual Studio and as a user control that you can use in your applications.

I think it will do just what you are after.