# Showing an XML file in a form with C#

Tags: c#, winforms

it might sound stupid, but I need a way to take an XML file / string, and show it to a user in a form.
I'm currently trying to use the WebBrowser control, but its Document field is read only. I tried setting DocumentText instead but it seems to be accepting HTML only. What control should I use? It can be anything in WinForms or Infragistics.
Also, if there's a .NET XML parser, I'd love to know.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show XML file in WinForms app with IE-like coloring and collapsing nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451901/show-xml-file-in-winforms-app-with-ie-like-coloring-and-collapsing-nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [`DocumentText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) instead.  See [this](http://blorgh.wordpress.com/2006/10/17/displaying-xml-in-the-net-webbrowser-control/) post for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Give [XmlVisualizer](http://www.codeplex.com/XmlVisualizer) a try. Also you might want to take a look at the following posts:
http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/xml/winform-filter-xml-cs.aspx
[Show XML file in WinForms app with IE-like coloring and collapsing nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451901/show-xml-file-in-winforms-app-with-ie-like-coloring-and-collapsing-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Load the document with XmlDocument.Load().  Then use XmlDocument.OuterXml...